# Can't resolve hostname in sub-network

Tags: dns, dhcp, dnsmasq, hostapd

I have a raspberry pi (192.168.1.1) set up as an AP for a few devices. The WIFI connection works,
DHCP also seems to give out valid addresses.
The issue is that none of the devices in the network are able to resolve the hostname of the pi, 'home'.
Here are some configuration files:

```
/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1       home
```

```
/etc/dnsmasq.conf
interface=wlan0
no-dhcp-interface=eth0

dhcp-range=192.168.1.2,192.168.1.254,12h

dhcp-option=option:dns-server,192.168.1.1
log-queries
log-facility=/tmp/dnsmasq.log
```

```
/etc/dhcpcd.conf
interface wlan0
        static ip_address=192.168.1.1/24
        static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1
        nohook wpa_supplicant
```

```
/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
# WLAN-Router-Betrieb

# Schnittstelle und Treiber
interface=wlan0
#driver=nl80211

# WLAN-Konfiguration
ssid=HomeNetwork
channel=2
hw_mode=g
ieee80211n=1
ieee80211d=1
country_code=DE
wmm_enabled=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=1
max_num_sta=255

# WLAN-Verschlüsselung
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_passphrase=xxxxxxx

ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
```

```
/var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases
1609402473 3c:71:bf:3a:09:c2 192.168.1.67 living-shelf *
1609402474 dc:4f:22:aa:08:1e 192.168.1.42 living-computer-light *
1609402473 dc:4f:22:92:75:da 192.168.1.215 living-beamer *
1609402647 c8:2b:96:53:79:a5 192.168.1.94 living-heater-carpet *
1609400799 dc:4f:22:a7:e5:4d 192.168.1.186 living-light *
1609402473 84:0d:8e:aa:81:7c 192.168.1.98 kitchen-passage *
1609402514 3c:71:bf:3a:12:8f 192.168.1.158 living-wallclock *
1609402652 c8:2b:96:53:77:bd 192.168.1.227 tasmota-printer *
```

My questions are:

1. Which component of my AP-pi should recognize a DNS query as a hostname of one of the devices and resolve it?
2. What do I have to set up in order for all the devices in the network to be able to reach each other through their hostnames?
3. What is required for the devices to be able to reach the AP-pi by its hostname?

Answer (score 1):

> Which component of my AP-pi should recognize a DNS query as a hostname of one of the devices and resolve it?

You need the DHCP server and the DNS server working together. In your case, dnsmasq performs both tasks at the same time; its built-in DNS service will look at the DHCP lease table automatically.

DNS queries are of course handled by the DNS server, but DHCP is the component which *collects* hostnames that other computers send as part of their lease requests, and stores them in a way that the DNS server understands.

(Technically, self-registration via DNS also exists but you'll only find it in Active Directory environments, not in basic dnsmasq LANs.)

> What do I have to set up in order for all the devices in the network to be able to reach each other through their hostnames?

Dnsmasq should advertise only itself as `dns-server` and not any other address. It seems you already have this.

You *might* need to specify a `domain` for this to work, however, as some devices will refuse to resolve single-component names. To avoid the problem you can define a domain suffix, such as `lan` (or the officially reserved `home.arpa`) that all your names will be grouped under.

The suffix can be advertised via DHCP so that you won't need to actually type it – the devices will automatically append it whenever you enter a single component name.

```
domain = lan
dhcp-option = option:domain-name, lan
```

This would result in names like `kitchen-toaster.lan`, but the DHCP option would avoid the need to actually *type* the `.lan` bit.

> What is required for the devices to be able to reach the AP-pi by its hostname?

The /etc/hosts entry needs to contain an IP address that makes sense to other devices. In other words, it has to be 192.168.1.1, not a loopback address.

It might be better to define the name directly in dnsmasq using `host-entry`.

```
host-entry = home, 192.168.1.1
```

If you use a domain suffix, it has to be specified in each host entry:

```
domain = home.arpa
host-entry = home.home.arpa, 192.168.1.1
dhcp-option = option:domain-name, home.arpa
```

Answer (score -1):

These are a lot of questions, unfortunately I am not able to answer them. But I do know a solution.
You can setup a PiHole instance on the Raspberry Pi and manually add a DNS entry for you Raspberry Pi.